# Complete series expansion of $\frac{1}{1+f(x)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion

I have to find, in a closed form, the n-th coefficients of the series expansion for small $x$ of
$$
\frac{1}{1+f(x)}
$$
knowing that $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_nx^{n}$. I know that, by Taylor's theorem, the answer is $D^{n}[\frac{1}{1+f(x)}]$ where D is the derivative operator, but the derivative becomes very difficult.
Also, I tried to use the geometric series writing:
$$
\frac{1}{1+f(x)} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n} f(x)^{n}
$$
but I couldn't find an easy way to use the multinomial theorem.

Thanks

Comment: You could just take the reciprocal of the series of $f(x)+1$ and solve for the coefficients and get a formula by induction.

Comment: @Hobbyist: I am not sure that "just take" is that easy.

Comment: It's not that hard. If you write down the series for $f(x)+1$ then let its reciprocal be say $c_0+c_1x+c_2x^2+\cdots$ then you can say the product of the constant terms is $1,$ then the coefficients of $x^n$ is zero for all $n,$ and it is not that hard to solve for $c_0, c_1,\dots$

Comment: You could try [Faa di Bruno's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula), but it's not going to be closed-form.  The formula for the $n$'th derivative will involve all of $a_0, a_1, \ldots, a_n$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Yes, that's the way thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Write

$$y(1+f)=1.$$

By differentiation,

$$y'(1+f)+yf'=0$$
$$y''(1+f)+2y'f'+yf''=0$$
$$y'''(1+f)+3y''f'+3y'f''+f'''=0$$
$$\cdots$$

and taken at $x=0$,

$$y_0=1$$
$$y'_0+y_0a_1=0$$
$$y''_0+2y'_0a_1+2y_0a_2=0$$
$$y'''_0+3y''_0a_1+3\cdot2y'_0a_2+3!y_0a_3=0$$
$$\cdots$$
or
$$y_0=1$$
$$y'_0+a_1=0$$
$$y''_0-2a_1^2+2a_2=0$$
$$y'''_0+3\cdot2(a_1^2-a_2)a_1-3\cdot2a_1a_2+3!a_3=0$$
$$\cdots$$

Hard to see regularity emerge, maybe with more terms... A recursive formula is possible, from

$$\sum_{k=0}^n \binom nky_0^{(n-k)}k!a_k=0$$ or

$$y_0^{(n)}=-n!\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{y_0^{(n-k)}a_k}{(n-k)!}.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

I tried to use [Faa di Bruno's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula), following the idea of @RobertIstrael. 
We have:
$$
f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_nx^{n}
$$
with $a_n=\frac{D^{n}[f(x)]}{n!}$ for $x=0$. We have also:
$$
g(f(x)) = \frac{1}{1+f(x)} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} w_nx^{n} 
$$
and we know that $w_n=\frac{D^{n}[g(f(x))]}{n!}$ calculated in $x=0$. 
Then using the Faa di Bruno's formula with the same notation of wiki's page, but with the rule of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ exchanged we have:
$$
D^{n}[f(x)] = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}(k-1)!}{(1+f(x))^{k}}B_{n,k}(f'(x),f''(x),...,f^{n-k+1}(x))
$$
When we calculate this expression for $x=0$ we have 
$$
 w_n=\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{k=1}^{n} (-1)^{k-1}(k-1)!B_{n,k}(a_1,2a_2,...,(n-k+1)!a_{n-k+1})
$$
It is not very simple and beautiful, but I do not know if it can do better.